# Numba not supporting NumPy arrays in nopython mode

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am trying to use numba. I kept getting a traceback error. I couldn't figure it out. I went to their [5-minute guide](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html) page and used one of their MWEs. That also doesn't work, and gives me the same error:

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(100).reshape(10, 10)

@jit(nopython=True) # Set "nopython" mode for best performance, equivalent to @njit
def go_fast(a): # Function is compiled to machine code when called the first time
    trace = 0.0
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):   # Numba likes loops
        trace += np.tanh(a[i, i]) # Numba likes NumPy functions
    return a + trace              # Numba likes NumPy broadcasting

print(go_fast(x))
```

This gives me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\aaron\OneDrive - Northwestern University\Documents\School\Year 2\ECON 483-1\PS1\pset1.ipynb Cell 10 in <cell line: 10>()
      7         trace += np.tanh(a[i, i]) # Numba likes NumPy functions
      8     return a + trace              # Numba likes NumPy broadcasting
---> 10 print(go_fast(x))

TypeError: expected dtype object, got 'numpy.dtype[float64]'
```

This is somewhat similar to what I was trying to do (pass a numpy array as an argument), so this should serve as a reasonable example. What am I missing?

Python: 3.8.8

NumPy: 1.20.1

Numba: 0.48.0+0.gcc7e7c7.dirty

Comment: The code works for me. What version of python/numba/numpy are you using?

Comment: Added the version numbers

Comment: Also works for me. Can you check if it is a problem with Numba or just with your print function (which should of course also work with a Numpy array)?

Comment: I think this was specific to my numba version. I use Anaconda and it wasn't updating numba. I manually forced it to install 0.55.1, and it works now (and is amazing, as always).